Sort list of time strings (e.g. 1 hour, 1 week) by length of time
I have a list of strings that I want to use as duration filter options. They are currently sorted alphabetically but I want them to be sorted by length of time. Is this possible?
The strings are:
['1 day', '2 days', '2 weeks', '3 days', '3 hours', '4 days']

What I want is:
['3 hours', '1 day', '2 days', '3 days', '4 days', '2 weeks']

Currently i'm sorting them alphabetically by:
const durations = [...new Set(this.courses.map(item => item.fields.duration).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)))];


There are several ways to achieve that result.. one is converting those durations to scalar using a common unit (hours in this case) so that they will be comparable for the sake of sorting.
In this demo I have a function that convert the duration given as string to scalar as the equivalent amount of hours that will be used in the sort callback function to decide which one comes first in the sort order.
I see other answers came before this one.. I guess this one doesn't add that much.


const data = ['1 day', '2 days', '2 weeks', '3 days', '3 hours', '4 days'];

function timeToHours(time){

  const units = {hour: 1, day: 24, week: 24*7};

  const parts = time.match(/^(\d+)\s(hour|day|week)s?$/);
  if (!parts)
    throw new Error(`'${time}' - Unexpected time format`);  
  const scalar = parseInt(parts[1]);
  const hours = units[parts[2]];

  return hours*scalar;
}

try {
  const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => timeToHours(a) - timeToHours(b)); 
  console.log(sorted);
  /*
  =>
    [
      "3 hours",
      "1 day",
      "2 days",
      "3 days",
      "4 days",
      "2 weeks"
    ]
  */
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`error occurred! - ${error}`);
}




@Yogi thank you for highlighting that.. I also added now the error handling for scenarios where the duration is not valid when parsed

Minor suggestion: Change the lookup table definition to const units = {hour: 1, day: 24, week: 7 * 24 }; so it's more obviously correct by inspection (any JS engine worth its salt will constant-fold the expression anyway, and while basically everyone capable of will know seven days in a week, 24 hours in a day, off the top of their head, fewer know 168 hours in a week quite so readily). Costs nothing to do it, and saves maintainers a little mental overhead, what's not to like?

Yes I agree… by the way I feel this answer was too much rewarded

First, create a method to convert the list to the minimum time period which is hours,
For example

1 day = 24 hours
1 week = 24 * 7 hours

const convertToHours = (duration) => {
  const [value, unit] = duration.split(' ');
  const num = parseInt(value, 10);

  switch (unit) {
    case 'hour':
    case 'hours':
      return num;
    case 'day':
    case 'days':
      return num * 24;
    case 'week':
    case 'weeks':
      return num * 24 * 7;
    default:
      return num;
  }
};


Then sort the list by comparing the result of convertToHours method.
const sortedDurations = durations.sort((a, b) => convertToHours(a) - convertToHours(b));

This is working codesnippet


const durations = ['1 day', '2 days', '2 weeks', '3 days', '3 hours', '4 days'];

const convertToHours = (duration) => {
  const [value, unit] = duration.split(' ');
  const num = parseInt(value, 10);

  switch (unit) {
    case 'hour':
    case 'hours':
      return num;
    case 'day':
    case 'days':
      return num * 24;
    case 'week':
    case 'weeks':
      return num * 24 * 7;
    default:
      return num;
  }
};


const sortedDurations = durations.sort((a, b) => convertToHours(a) - convertToHours(b));

console.log(sortedDurations);



You can use regular expressions for extracting the value and unit in case there are extra spaces/new lines /(\d+)\s*(\w+)/.


const durations = ['1  day', '2 days\n', '2 \n weeks', '3 days', '3 hours', '4 days'];

const convertToHours = (duration) => {
  const match = duration.match(/(\d+)\s*(\w+)/);
  if (!match) return 0;

  const num = +match[1];
  const unit = match[2];

  switch (unit) {
    case 'hour':
    case 'hours':
      return num;
    case 'day':
    case 'days':
      return num * 24;
    case 'week':
    case 'weeks':
      return num * 24 * 7;
    default:
      return num;
  }
};


const sortedDurations = durations.sort((a, b) => convertToHours(a) - convertToHours(b));

console.log(sortedDurations);




For every type of time hour, day and week I assign the equivalent number of minutes and I use it to create a map to assign a value to every time in array, in order to sort it on value calculated.


const minutes = {
    h: 60,
    d: 1440,
    w: 10080,
    m: 43800
}

const durationsStrings = ['1 day', '2 days', '2 weeks', '3 days', '1 hours', '4 days']

console.log((durationsStrings.map(item => {
    return {
    "value": item.split(" ")[0]*minutes[item.split(" ")[1].charAt(0)],
    "duration": item
}}).sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)).map(item => item.duration))




AFAIK you can not parse those "range-strings" into a comparable format with vanilla-js itself, you could however write some code that does so, or use a library that can do this somehow, in example dayjs
Personally i would just blow up the inital array with comparable data, something like:
[
  {
    label: '1 day',
    hours: 24
  },
  {
    label: '2 days',
    hours: 48
  },
  {
    label: '3 hours',
    hours: 3
  }
]

And then you would sort for hours and only display label
